# Can't get sass + compass + susy installed due to version conflict

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm working with Sass, Compass and Susy on OSX / Terminal. But I can't get Susy to work together with Sass and Compass. What I've done:

```
sudo gem install sass
sass -v
```

Returns: Sass 3.3.0 (Maptastic Maple)

```
sudo gem install compass
```

This seems to also install sass-3.2.14.gem, then the compass-0.12.3.gem.

```
compass -v
```

returns: Compass 0.12.3 (Alnilam)

Everything until this point seems to work fine; I can create a Compass project and work with it. Then I try to install Susy:

```
sudo gem install susy --pre
```

or just

```
sudo gem install susy
```

This seems to install susy-2.0.0

Than I run:

```
compass create /Users/tom/Thomas/htdocs/susi4-test -r susy -u susy
```

And I get this error:

```
Gem::LoadError on line 2064 of /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.0.0, because sass-3.2.14 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

So there seems to be a problem with the compatibility of the different versions. What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Your gems are incompatible. Installing the latest Compass via `gem install compass --pre` should fix the problem.

Comment: It looks like other folks have had this problem too. @stefan - can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @KatieK sure, I've added an answer with a brief explanation as a reference.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The dependencies are incompatible: [susy 2.0.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/susy/versions/2.0.0) depends on `sass ~> 3.3.0` whereas [compass 0.12.3](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/0.12.3) depends on `sass = 3.2.14`.

The error message says the same:

> Unable to activate susy-2.0.0, because sass-3.2.14 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)

You can a) **downgrade susy** to a version that's working with sass 3.2.14 or b) **upgrade compass** to a version compatible with sass 3.3.x.

A compatible version is [compass 1.0.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0) (or later) depending on `sass < 3.5, >= 3.3.13`. You can install it via

```
gem update compass
```

It might be easier to use a gem manager like [Bundler](http://bundler.io). It automatically resolves dependencies and installs the appropriate versions.

Comment: Great help here... Tahnk you so much.
Greetings from Vienna,
Thomas

Comment: hey there the compass version is 1.0.0.alpha.20, the link is ok, but the text is not =/

Comment: @Arruda thanks, I've updated my answer (compass 1.0.0 has been released)

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install compass --pre
```

when you install compass lastest version will have error like:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::UnsatisfiableDependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependency: 'compass (= 1.0.0.alpha.19)' requires 'compass-core (~> 1.0.0.alpha.19)'
```

You should install compass-core first

```
gem install compass-core
```

Answer (score -2):

The best way without a doubt is to install Susy via the Compass Susy Plugin. This will avoid conflicts with other Compass projects that require the current version.

Commands:

```
gem install compass
gem install compass-susy-plugin
```

Comment: This does not work because Compass Susy Plugin is the latest version (now)