# Sass Compile Error

Tags: ruby, terminal, sass

I am having a problem with a project I am working on where I get the following error when I try to watch. Please see the screen attached. Has anyone ever had this problem and does anyone have suggestions? I have had a look on Google and still cant seem to get it working correctly.

I am using Mavericks and project uses Sass with Susy Framework. Any suggestions would be great.

Screenshot here: http://www.glenwheeler.co.uk/uploads/terminalerror.png

**Command as follows:**

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in`rescue in require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in`'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in`each'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in`'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in`each'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in`require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in`block in '
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in `fallback_load_path'
>     from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in`'
>     from /usr/bin/compass:23:in `load'
>     from /usr/bin/compass:23:in`'

Comment: Upgrading compass should fix this, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22313017/477037

Comment: Hi Martin, I tried the upgrade. I still have the same error.