# Error to compile susy on Mavericks ruby version

Tags: ruby, susy-compass

This is my problem I update susy version to susy (2.1.2, 2.1.1) sass (3.3.6, 3.3.4) ruby 2.0.0p0.

Then I begin to work with compass watch and in compile send my this error:

```
WARNING: Something went horribly wrong here. Try adjusting your variables.
     on line 104 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_media.scss, in `at-breakpoint'
     from line 83 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/susy-1.0.9/sass/susy/_grid.scss, in `container'
     from line 36 of /proyectos/ideas about ideas/theme/ideasaboutideas/sass/ideasaboutideas.styles.scss
```

I dont know why my project try to use the older version and not the newest one. How can I change it?

Comment: Try uninstalling the older version with `gem uninstall susy` (or `sudo gem uninstall susy` in some cases).

Comment: I check and the new version of susy is there, but compass dont use it to copile.

Answer (score 2):

Susy is incompatible with that compass version ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299466/cant-get-sass-compass-susy-installed-on-osx-due-to-version-conflict)) so I think compass will only work with the old version.

You could install the current [alpha version](https://rubygems.org/gems/compass/versions/1.0.0.alpha.19) which should work.

Comment: I update but still dont work is like if im using a older version and dont use the newer one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using Bundler to manage dependencies? It's easy to install and works for me.

Comment: First I install bundler in my main ruby so my problem convert in a double problem! right now I install RVM then bundler and I think the problem is solve.