# Susy not working with Compass and Sass

Tags: sass, compass-sass, susy-compass

I'm getting a Gem:ConflictError when trying to run Susy. I noticed that Compass depends on sass 3.2.19 But the latest Susy depends on Sass (< 3.5, >= 3.3.0). I'm a nubie at this so what can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get sass + compass + susy installed on OSX due to version conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299466/cant-get-sass-compass-susy-installed-on-osx-due-to-version-conflict)

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your Compass to 1.0.0 or later.

```
gem install compass --pre
```

Comment: If the question has been answered before, we prefer to close duplicates rather than answering them.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, use Bundler. Provided your Gemfile includes sass 3.3, Bundler will add the other dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

So I was able to answer my own question by combining some of the answers I found here.

First uninstall compass an then do the follow:

- Install rvm (stable with ruby add --insecure flag for SSL related issues) `$\curl -sSL --insecure https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`
- Restart Terminal / Resource your profile
- Run `rvm requirements --with-gcc=clang` You won't have to update Ruby because you downloaded the last stable version
- And last step to run gem install compass --pre

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into the same problem!