# install Singularitygs on windows - compass sass conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, compass-sass, singularitygs

I've followed this quick walkthrough guide: http://vimeo.com/63509346
and had run the following commands:

1. `gem install compass`
2. `gem install singularitygs`

All went fine, no errors on the installation part.

Unfortunately, when running this command:

`compass create foobar -r singularitygs --using singularitygs`

I get this error:

```
Gem::LoadError on line ["2007"] of C: Unable to activate singularitygs-1.2.3, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~
> 3.3.0)
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Now, as a matter of fact, I did have `sass-3.3.10` installed, but after getting this error and reading the installation guide here: https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation I have uninstalled `sass` completely and re-run the command `gem install compass` so it will install `sass-2.x.x` as needed.
But for some reason, I still cannot run the `compass create...` - I get the same error.

These are all the gems installed on my pc:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
breakpoint (2.4.6)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (0.12.7)
fssm (0.2.10)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sass (3.2.19)
sassy-maps (0.4.0)
singularitygs (1.2.3)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

Any help is appreciated, please let me know if any further data is needed.

Cheers,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get sass + compass + susy installed due to version conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299466/cant-get-sass-compass-susy-installed-due-to-version-conflict)

Comment: I saw it but I'm not using Susy so I thought it might be something else (although it looks similar)

Comment: That's why you search for the error (`Unable to activate because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (~> 3.3.0)`).  This is not a Susy or Singularity specific thing.

Comment: @cimmanon you are right... I eventually found the answer there. Thanks. Sorry for the duplication

Answer (score 1):

Create your foobar project with bundler.

First install bundler:

```
    gem install bundler
```

Create a "GemFile" in your folder and put in it:

```
    gem "sass", "~>3.2.0"
    gem "compass", "~>0.12.0"
    gem "singularitygs", "~>1.1.2"
```

Afterwards run:

```
    bundle install
    bundle exec compass create {project name} -r singularitygs --using singularitygs
```

as suggested in https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation

Comment: That's only going to give the OP Singularity 1.1.2.  The OP wants to install 1.2.3, which is incompatible with the listed Sass/Compass versions.

Comment: Does he? He only lists all installed gems on his pc.. Ziv, do you need this version 1.2.3?

Comment: yeah I prefer version 1.2.x since they have changed some API, so I believe I should get the later one so I could take future versions

Comment: Then use compatible versions, what's the problem?