# Cannot Get Susy 2 to work Compass and Sass

Tags: ruby, sass, susy-compass

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

addressable (2.3.6)
bundler (1.6.5)
celluloid (0.15.2)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8, 2.2.0)
chunky_png (1.3.1)
compass (0.12.7)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
compass-rails (2.0.0)
css_parser (1.3.5)
fssm (0.2.10)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
mini_portile (0.6.0)
multi_json (1.10.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
rake (10.3.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
sass (3.3.14, 3.2.19)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
susy (2.1.3)
timers (1.1.0)
version (1.0.0)

The Problem I am experiencing is that:

compass-0.12.7 depends on sass (~> 3.2.19)  and susy-2.1.3 depends on sass (< 3.5, >= 3.3.0).

I have installed Bundler as you can see but still get this error when implementing compass watch:

> Gem::LoadError on line ["1990"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb: Unable to activate susy-2.1.3, because sass-3.2.19 conflicts with sass (< 3.5, >= 3.3.0)
>   Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get sass + compass + susy installed due to version conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22299466/cant-get-sass-compass-susy-installed-due-to-version-conflict)

Answer (score -2):

Your Gemfile must include:

```
gem "susy", "~>2.1.0"
gem "sass", "~>3.3.0"
```

Then Bundler will install all of the correct dependencies. You don't need to uninstall earlier versions of SASS, but you can do, if you wish.

Answer (score -2):

I think your `suzy` and `sass` are new versions

Try uninstalling your compass first and install the newest version.

```
gem install compass --pre
```

After, just put this on your `sass` file.

```
@import "susyone"
```